# Trello API and PHP Integration

Tags: php, trello

I need some help with a trello integration, basically what I want to do is connect to trello, create a trello card and then move the card around in the different statuses based on what the user does in our op's system.

It needs to work with php etc etc etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes: Hire a software developer to build this for you, rather than hoping someone here will do it for free.

Comment: Okay. What are you using? means core php or any framework.

Comment: Use the [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference)